# Integrating web content into desktop java app

Tags: java, javafx, safari, recaptcha

I want to have a platform to open website in desktop app. I followed the guide using JavaFX `WebEngine` to show the website and succeeded.

```
import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.scene.Scene;import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine; 
import javafx.stage.Stage; 
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class JavaApplication7 extends Application {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    final WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    System.out.println(webEngine.isJavaScriptEnabled());
    webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webEngine.load("http://csgodouble.com");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    primaryStage.show();
}

}
```

But i got stuck when it show the reCaptcha v2 of Google:

[image]

It said upgrade browser. I tried to check version by loading whoer extend and it show I was using safari 2.0:

[image]

I need help in displaying this recaptcha in my `WebView` or if there is any other solution to display website with reCaptcha but this JavaFX still okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the user agent to emulate a common browser, such as Safari 9.1.1:

```
webEngine.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17");
```